# Product rule in differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose I want to know how $f(x)g(x)$ changes when $x$ increases.

I compute $\frac{d(f(x)g(x))}{dx}=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$ using the product rule.

However the sign of $f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$ turns out to be indeterminate: $f'(x)g(x)<0$ while $f(x)g'(x)>0$ and I know nothing about the magnitudes of these functions.

If I decide to then compute $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ independently, will I always get that one of the functions is increasing in $x$ while the other is decreasing in $x$?

Comment: How do you know that $f’(x)g(x)<0$ and $f(x)g’(x)>0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because your values also depend on whether the values of f(x) and g(x) are above the x axis or not.

Comment: Be wary of posting an Answer significantly shorter than the Question it responds to.  Your idea may very well be fleshed out with an example or other exposition into good content, but as is it scarcely amounts to a Comment.